# Creating Flattened Object from Map (Reduce complexity of View query) - Mongo DB

Tags: mongodb, view, aggregation-framework

I have to create a view for Mongo DB. I came up with something like below:-

```
db.createView("weNeed","Master",
 [
{$project:
     {
         _id:"$_id",
         documents:{
            $concatArrays:[
             {$ifNull:
             [{$map:{
                input:"$documents.COMPLETED",
                 as:"document",
                 in:{
                     entity:"$name",
                     status:"COMPLETED",
                     name:"$$document.name",
                     category:"$$document.category",
                     description:"$$document.description",
                     submittedDate:"$$document.submittedDate",
                     expirationDate:"$$document.expirationDate"

                     }
             }},[]]},
             {$ifNull:
             [{$map:{
                input:"$documents.REQUIRED",
                 as:"document",
                 in:{ entity:"$name",
                     status:"REQUIRED",
                     name:"$$document.name",
                     category:"$$document.category",
                     description:"$$document.description",
                     submittedDate:"$$document.submittedDate",
                     expirationDate:"$$document.expirationDate"
                     }
             }},[]]},
             {$ifNull:
             [{$map:{
                input:"$documents.DEFERRED",
                 as:"document",
                 in:{ entity:"$name",
                     status:"DEFERRED",
                     name:"$$document.name",
                     category:"$$document.category",
                     description:"$$document.description",
                     submittedDate:"$$document.submittedDate",
                     expirationDate:"$$document.expirationDate"
                     }
             }},[]]}
             ]
         }
     }
     }
     ]
     )
```

`documents` is an Object something like below:-

```
 "COMPLETED" : [ 
            {
                "externalIds" : {
                    "fenergo" : "35"
                },
                "name" : "CRS Self Certification",
                "category" : "Tax",
                "description" : "CRS Self Certification",
                "submittedDate" : ISODate("2017-12-05T18:48:26.183Z"),
            }
}],
"UNRELATED" : [ 
            {
                "externalIds" : {
                    "fenergo" : "35"
                },
                "name" : "CRS Self Certification",
                "category" : "Tax",
                "description" : "CRS Self Certification",
                "submittedDate" : ISODate("2017-12-05T18:48:26.183Z"),
            }]
```

I unfortunately had to repeat map code to pull out the document for each status and then create flattened Object for each Object in the array returned.

Wanted output it like below:-

```
 "documents" : [ 
                {
                   "status":"COMPLETED",
                    "name" : "CRS Self Certification",
                    "category" : "Tax",
                    "description" : "CRS Self Certification",
                    "submittedDate" : ISODate("2017-12-05T18:48:26.183Z"),
                },
                {
                   "status":"UNRELATED",
                    "name" : "CRS Self Certification",
                    "category" : "Tax",
                    "description" : "CRS Self Certification",
                    "submittedDate" : ISODate("2017-12-05T18:48:26.183Z"),
                }
```

Is there any way that I don't need to repeat it for all the keys of my object? As I think if tomorrow I have another status this is going to be a very bad approach.

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rewrite your project stage to below in 3.6.

```
  {
  "$project":{
    "documents":{
      "$reduce":{
        "input":{"$objectToArray":"$documents"},
        "initialValue":[],
        "in":{"$concatArrays":["$$value", {"$map":{ input:"$$this.v",  as:"mvalue", in:{"$mergeObjects":[{"status":"$$this.k"}, "$$mvalue"]} }}]}
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: this won't work as merge object requires object and the value I have is a list. Still good attempt

Comment: sorry we may need a map stage. let me see what I can do.

Comment: added $map stage. give it a try.

Comment: It did the job very well!